# How to inject active_admin header into custom layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm try to custom active_admin layout for specific action.But I dont know how can i add active_admin's header into my custom layout?

app/admin/provider.rb
I render edit page with custom_active_admin layout

```rb
controller do
 def edit
   @provider = Provider.find(params[:id])
   render 'admin/providers/edit', layout: 'custom_active_admin'
 end
 ...
end
```

app/views/admin/providers/edit.html.haml

```
= semantic_form_for ...
  = f.inputs 'Location', for: :location do |location|
    = location.input :postal_code
    = location.input :prefecture
```

app/views/layouts/custom_active_admin.html.haml
I'm try to custom layout for my special action

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = csp_meta_tag
    ...
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'custom_active_admin', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'custom_active_admin'

  %body.new.active_admin.logged_in.admin_namespace
    #header
      = yield :head
    .wrapper.without_sidebar#active_admin_content
      .main_content_wrapper
        .alert-message-container
        = yield
```

My custom action can work fine. But i need add header to top page like those pages using default active_admin layout. How i can do it? Thanks.

Comment: What about adding the action into an active admin, rather than creating a custom controller and action? https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html

Comment: @agbodike I custom edit and update action because I'm implement upload image direct to S3 use jquery-fileupload and edit page need a little change compared to default edit page. So i import js and css to custom layout to use for my special action.

Comment: I still don't see why you need a separate layout. You can create a view for the action you have, what part of the problem requires a separate layout?

Comment: @agbodike I want add some JS and CSS for only my special action page so i think separate layout is needed. If use default layout, I think must import js and css into body of page. Is it ok ?

Comment: OK, I see what you are trying to do, and don't think you need at separate layout, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register custom stylesheets and javascript in the config initializer. I recommend just adding the CSS & JS into your active admin config:

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb

# == Register Stylesheets & Javascripts
#
# We recommend using the built in Active Admin layout and loading
# up your own stylesheets / javascripts to customize the look
# and feel.
#
# To load a stylesheet:
   config.register_stylesheet 'my_stylesheet.css'
#
# You can provide an options hash for more control, which is passed along to stylesheet_link_tag():
#   config.register_stylesheet 'my_print_stylesheet.css', media: :print
#
# To load a javascript file:
   config.register_javascript 'my_javascript.js'
```

If you feel strongly that the JS should only be on that single view, you can include it in the view itself.

for example, in an app I have, we display charts on 1 page of active admin, and have included the chart library at the top of the view:

```
= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick"

%h2 History chart

= line_chart participant.linear_chart_payload, curve: false
```

The script goes in the body, which is not ideal, but it works fine. I don't think there's a need to put CSS in the view itself, as you should be able to use selectors to ensure that the CSS only applies to the view you need it to.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's work fine. My custom page use bootstrap for style. If it make my page render wrong, I will style it by myself. about include JS I think placing scripts at the bottom of the <body> element improves the display speed, because script interpretation slows down the display.

Comment: This does not work anymore, because config.register_stylesheet is deprecated.